# Try to use quatitize.js but got error message "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'palette'"

Tags: javascript

I am learning to use the [quantitize.js](https://gist.github.com/nrabinowitz/1104622)
 but getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'palette'". I don't know what is wrong. PLease help. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
<div></div>

<script
src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        /*!
         * quantize.js Copyright 2008 Nick Rabinowitz.
         * Licensed under the MIT license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
         */

         // fill out a couple protovis dependencies
        /*!
         * Block below copied from Protovis: http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/
         * Copyright 2010 Stanford Visualization Group
         * Licensed under the BSD License: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php
         */
        if (!pv) {
            var pv = {
                map: function (array, f) {
                    var o = {};
                    return f ? array.map(function (d, i) {
                        o.index = i;
                        return f.call(o, d);
                    }) : array.slice();
                },
                naturalOrder: function (a, b) {
                    return (a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0);
                },
                sum: function (array, f) {
                    var o = {};
                    return array.reduce(f ? function (p, d, i) {
                        o.index = i;
                        return p + f.call(o, d);
                    } : function (p, d) {
                        return p + d;
                    }, 0);
                },
                max: function (array, f) {
                    return Math.max.apply(null, f ? pv.map(array, f) : array);
                }
            };
        }



        /**
         * Basic Javascript port of the MMCQ (modified median cut quantization)
         * algorithm from the Leptonica library (http://www.leptonica.com/).
         * Returns a color map you can use to map original pixels to the reduced
         * palette. Still a work in progress.
         *
         * @author Nick Rabinowitz
         * @example
         */
         // array of pixels as [R,G,B] arrays
        var myPixels = [
            [190, 197, 190],
            [202, 204, 200],
            [207, 214, 210],
            [211, 214, 211],
            [205, 207, 207]
            // etc
        ];
        var maxColors = 4;

        var cmap = MMCQ.quantize(myPixels, maxColors);
        var newPalette = cmap.palette();
        var newPixels = myPixels.map(function (p) {
            return cmap.map(p);
        });

         // */
        var MMCQ = (function () {
            // private constants
            var sigbits = 5,
                rshift = 8 - sigbits,
                maxIterations = 1000,
                fractByPopulations = 0.75;

            // get reduced-space color index for a pixel

            function getColorIndex(r, g, b) {
                return (r << (2 * sigbits)) + (g << sigbits) + b;
            }

            // Simple priority queue

            function PQueue(comparator) {
                var contents = [],
                    sorted = false;

                function sort() {
                    contents.sort(comparator);
                    sorted = true;
                }

                return {
                    push: function (o) {
                        contents.push(o);
                        sorted = false;
                    },
                    peek: function (index) {
                        if (!sorted) sort();
                        if (index === undefined) index = contents.length - 1;
                        return contents[index];
                    },
                    pop: function () {
                        if (!sorted) sort();
                        return contents.pop();
                    },
                    size: function () {
                        return contents.length;
                    },
                    map: function (f) {
                        return contents.map(f);
                    },
                    debug: function () {
                        if (!sorted) sort();
                        return contents;
                    }
                };
            }

            // 3d color space box

            function VBox(r1, r2, g1, g2, b1, b2, histo) {
                var vbox = this;
                vbox.r1 = r1;
                vbox.r2 = r2;
                vbox.g1 = g1;
                vbox.g2 = g2;
                vbox.b1 = b1;
                vbox.b2 = b2;
                vbox.histo = histo;
            }
            VBox.prototype = {
                volume: function (force) {
                    var vbox = this;
                    if (!vbox._volume || force) {
                        vbox._volume = ((vbox.r2 - vbox.r1 + 1) * (vbox.g2 - vbox.g1 + 1) * (vbox.b2 - vbox.b1 + 1));
                    }
                    return vbox._volume;
                },
                count: function (force) {
                    var vbox = this,
                        histo = vbox.histo;
                    if (!vbox._count_set || force) {
                        var npix = 0,
                            i, j, k;
                        for (i = vbox.r1; i <= vbox.r2; i++) {
                            for (j = vbox.g1; j <= vbox.g2; j++) {
                                for (k = vbox.b1; k <= vbox.b2; k++) {
                                    index = getColorIndex(i, j, k);
                                    npix += (histo[index] || 0);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        vbox._count = npix;
                        vbox._count_set = true;
                    }
                    return vbox._count;
                },
                copy: function () {
                    var vbox = this;
                    return new VBox(vbox.r1, vbox.r2, vbox.g1, vbox.g2, vbox.b1, vbox.b2, vbox.histo);
                },
                avg: function (force) {
                    var vbox = this,
                        histo = vbox.histo;
                    if (!vbox._avg || force) {
                        var ntot = 0,
                            mult = 1 << (8 - sigbits),
                            rsum = 0,
                            gsum = 0,
                            bsum = 0,
                            hval,
                            i, j, k, histoindex;
                        for (i = vbox.r1; i <= vbox.r2; i++) {
                            for (j = vbox.g1; j <= vbox.g2; j++) {
                                for (k = vbox.b1; k <= vbox.b2; k++) {
                                    histoindex = getColorIndex(i, j, k);
                                    hval = histo[histoindex] || 0;
                                    ntot += hval;
                                    rsum += (hval * (i + 0.5) * mult);
                                    gsum += (hval * (j + 0.5) * mult);
                                    bsum += (hval * (k + 0.5) * mult);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (ntot) {
                            vbox._avg = [~~(rsum / ntot), ~~ (gsum / ntot), ~~ (bsum / ntot)];
                        } else {
                            //                    console.log('empty box');
                            vbox._avg = [~~(mult * (vbox.r1 + vbox.r2 + 1) / 2), ~~ (mult * (vbox.g1 + vbox.g2 + 1) / 2), ~~ (mult * (vbox.b1 + vbox.b2 + 1) / 2)];
                        }
                    }
                    return vbox._avg;
                },
                contains: function (pixel) {
                    var vbox = this,
                        rval = pixel[0] >> rshift;
                    gval = pixel[1] >> rshift;
                    bval = pixel[2] >> rshift;
                    return (rval >= vbox.r1 && rval <= vbox.r2 &&
                        gval >= vbox.g1 && rval <= vbox.g2 &&
                        bval >= vbox.b1 && rval <= vbox.b2);
                }
            };

            // Color map

            function CMap() {
                this.vboxes = new PQueue(function (a, b) {
                    return pv.naturalOrder(
                        a.vbox.count() * a.vbox.volume(),
                        b.vbox.count() * b.vbox.volume()
                    )
                });;
            }
            CMap.prototype = {
                push: function (vbox) {
                    this.vboxes.push({
                        vbox: vbox,
                        color: vbox.avg()
                    });
                },
                palette: function () {
                    return this.vboxes.map(function (vb) {
                        return vb.color
                    });
                },
                size: function () {
                    return this.vboxes.size();
                },
                map: function (color) {
                    var vboxes = this.vboxes;
                    for (var i = 0; i < vboxes.size(); i++) {
                        if (vboxes.peek(i).vbox.contains(color)) {
                            return vboxes.peek(i).color;
                        }
                    }
                    return this.nearest(color);
                },
                nearest: function (color) {
                    var vboxes = this.vboxes,
                        d1, d2, pColor;
                    for (var i = 0; i < vboxes.size(); i++) {
                        d2 = Math.sqrt(
                            Math.pow(color[0] - vboxes.peek(i).color[0], 2) +
                            Math.pow(color[1] - vboxes.peek(i).color[1], 2) +
                            Math.pow(color[1] - vboxes.peek(i).color[1], 2)
                        );
                        if (d2 < d1 || d1 === undefined) {
                            d1 = d2;
                            pColor = vboxes.peek(i).color;
                        }
                    }
                    return pColor;
                },
                forcebw: function () {
                    // XXX: won't  work yet
                    var vboxes = this.vboxes;
                    vboxes.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return pv.naturalOrder(pv.sum(a.color), pv.sum(b.color))
                    });

                    // force darkest color to black if everything < 5
                    var lowest = vboxes[0].color;
                    if (lowest[0] < 5 && lowest[1] < 5 && lowest[2] < 5)
                        vboxes[0].color = [0, 0, 0];

                    // force lightest color to white if everything > 251
                    var idx = vboxes.length - 1,
                        highest = vboxes[idx].color;
                    if (highest[0] > 251 && highest[1] > 251 && highest[2] > 251)
                        vboxes[idx].color = [255, 255, 255];
                }
            };

            // histo (1-d array, giving the number of pixels in
            // each quantized region of color space), or null on error

            function getHisto(pixels) {
                var histosize = 1 << (3 * sigbits),
                    histo = new Array(histosize),
                    index, rval, gval, bval;
                pixels.forEach(function (pixel) {
                    rval = pixel[0] >> rshift;
                    gval = pixel[1] >> rshift;
                    bval = pixel[2] >> rshift;
                    index = getColorIndex(rval, gval, bval);
                    histo[index] = (histo[index] || 0) + 1;
                });
                return histo;
            }

            function vboxFromPixels(pixels, histo) {
                var rmin = 1000000,
                    rmax = 0,
                    gmin = 1000000,
                    gmax = 0,
                    bmin = 1000000,
                    bmax = 0,
                    rval, gval, bval;
                // find min/max
                pixels.forEach(function (pixel) {
                    rval = pixel[0] >> rshift;
                    gval = pixel[1] >> rshift;
                    bval = pixel[2] >> rshift;
                    if (rval < rmin) rmin = rval;
                    else if (rval > rmax) rmax = rval;
                    if (gval < gmin) gmin = gval;
                    else if (gval > gmax) gmax = gval;
                    if (bval < bmin) bmin = bval;
                    else if (bval > bmax) bmax = bval;
                });
                return new VBox(rmin, rmax, gmin, gmax, bmin, bmax, histo);
            }

            function medianCutApply(histo, vbox) {
                if (!vbox.count()) return;

                var rw = vbox.r2 - vbox.r1 + 1,
                    gw = vbox.g2 - vbox.g1 + 1,
                    bw = vbox.b2 - vbox.b1 + 1,
                    maxw = pv.max([rw, gw, bw]);
                // only one pixel, no split
                if (vbox.count() == 1) {
                    return [vbox.copy()]
                }
                /* Find the partial sum arrays along the selected axis. */
                var total = 0,
                    partialsum = [],
                    lookaheadsum = [],
                    i, j, k, sum, index;
                if (maxw == rw) {
                    for (i = vbox.r1; i <= vbox.r2; i++) {
                        sum = 0;
                        for (j = vbox.g1; j <= vbox.g2; j++) {
                            for (k = vbox.b1; k <= vbox.b2; k++) {
                                index = getColorIndex(i, j, k);
                                sum += (histo[index] || 0);
                            }
                        }
                        total += sum;
                        partialsum[i] = total;
                    }
                } else if (maxw == gw) {
                    for (i = vbox.g1; i <= vbox.g2; i++) {
                        sum = 0;
                        for (j = vbox.r1; j <= vbox.r2; j++) {
                            for (k = vbox.b1; k <= vbox.b2; k++) {
                                index = getColorIndex(j, i, k);
                                sum += (histo[index] || 0);
                            }
                        }
                        total += sum;
                        partialsum[i] = total;
                    }
                } else { /* maxw == bw */
                    for (i = vbox.b1; i <= vbox.b2; i++) {
                        sum = 0;
                        for (j = vbox.r1; j <= vbox.r2; j++) {
                            for (k = vbox.g1; k <= vbox.g2; k++) {
                                index = getColorIndex(j, k, i);
                                sum += (histo[index] || 0);
                            }
                        }
                        total += sum;
                        partialsum[i] = total;
                    }
                }
                partialsum.forEach(function (d, i) {
                    lookaheadsum[i] = total - d
                });

                function doCut(color) {
                    var dim1 = color + '1',
                        dim2 = color + '2',
                        left, right, vbox1, vbox2, d2, count2 = 0;
                    for (i = vbox[dim1]; i <= vbox[dim2]; i++) {
                        if (partialsum[i] > total / 2) {
                            vbox1 = vbox.copy();
                            vbox2 = vbox.copy();
                            left = i - vbox[dim1];
                            right = vbox[dim2] - i;
                            if (left <= right)
                                d2 = Math.min(vbox[dim2] - 1, ~~ (i + right / 2));
                            else d2 = Math.max(vbox[dim1], ~~ (i - 1 - left / 2));
                            // avoid 0-count boxes
                            while (!partialsum[d2]) d2++;
                            count2 = lookaheadsum[d2];
                            while (!count2 && partialsum[d2 - 1]) count2 = lookaheadsum[--d2];
                            // set dimensions
                            vbox1[dim2] = d2;
                            vbox2[dim1] = vbox1[dim2] + 1;
                            //                    console.log('vbox counts:', vbox.count(), vbox1.count(), vbox2.count());
                            return [vbox1, vbox2];
                        }
                    }

                }
                // determine the cut planes
                return maxw == rw ? doCut('r') :
                    maxw == gw ? doCut('g') :
                    doCut('b');
            }

            function quantize(pixels, maxcolors) {
                // short-circuit
                if (!pixels.length || maxcolors < 2 || maxcolors > 256) {
                    //            console.log('wrong number of maxcolors');
                    return false;
                }

                // XXX: check color content and convert to grayscale if insufficient

                var histo = getHisto(pixels),
                    histosize = 1 << (3 * sigbits);

                // check that we aren't below maxcolors already
                var nColors = 0;
                histo.forEach(function () {
                    nColors++
                });
                if (nColors <= maxcolors) {
                    // XXX: generate the new colors from the histo and return
                }

                // get the beginning vbox from the colors
                var vbox = vboxFromPixels(pixels, histo),
                    pq = new PQueue(function (a, b) {
                        return pv.naturalOrder(a.count(), b.count())
                    });
                pq.push(vbox);

                // inner function to do the iteration

                function iter(lh, target) {
                    var ncolors = 1,
                        niters = 0,
                        vbox;
                    while (niters < maxIterations) {
                        vbox = lh.pop();
                        if (!vbox.count()) { /* just put it back */
                            lh.push(vbox);
                            niters++;
                            continue;
                        }
                        // do the cut
                        var vboxes = medianCutApply(histo, vbox),
                            vbox1 = vboxes[0],
                            vbox2 = vboxes[1];

                        if (!vbox1) {
                            //                    console.log("vbox1 not defined; shouldn't happen!");
                            return;
                        }
                        lh.push(vbox1);
                        if (vbox2) { /* vbox2 can be null */
                            lh.push(vbox2);
                            ncolors++;
                        }
                        if (ncolors >= target) return;
                        if (niters++ > maxIterations) {
                            //                    console.log("infinite loop; perhaps too few pixels!");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // first set of colors, sorted by population
                iter(pq, fractByPopulations * maxcolors);

                // Re-sort by the product of pixel occupancy times the size in color space.
                var pq2 = new PQueue(function (a, b) {
                    return pv.naturalOrder(a.count() * a.volume(), b.count() * b.volume())
                });
                while (pq.size()) {
                    pq2.push(pq.pop());
                }

                // next set - generate the median cuts using the (npix * vol) sorting.
                iter(pq2, maxcolors - pq2.size());

                // calculate the actual colors
                var cmap = new CMap();
                while (pq2.size()) {
                    cmap.push(pq2.pop());
                }

                return cmap;
            }

            return {
                quantize: quantize
            }
        })();
    </script>
```

The code is from quantitize.js. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem is happening when it gets to the function 'quantize'. It seems you aren't passing it the pixels properly, or setting the maxcolors too high or too low.
Try adding some console.logs in it and see if pixels are 0 or max colors are bad.
:

```
function quantize(pixels, maxcolors) {
        // short-circuit
        if (!pixels.length || maxcolors < 2 || maxcolors > 256) {
            console.log('wrong number of maxcolors');
            console.log("pixellength: " + pixels.length);
            console.log("maxcolors:" + maxcolors);
            return false;

        }

        console.log(pixels.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open the link to the current version of the script, you will see that this section of the code is commented out. Also on lines 38 and 39 it is specified that:

```
 * Returns a color map you can use to map original pixels to the reduced
 * palette. Still a work in progress.
```

Therefore, I wouldn't expect it to work, perhaps there are some missing libraries. I suggest you update your code with the latest version at https://gist.github.com/nrabinowitz/1104622.

Also, you can keep your page clean and separate the module. For example create a subdirectory *assets*, put the quantize.js in there and in your page include:

```
  <script src="/assets/quantize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```